# How do I start/open an existing app in the emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I had someone build me an Android app ( a fairly simple Fiverr gig, I just want to use it to check how certain things look 'under the hood').

I'm a total noob with android, but I want it to run in the emulator.

I've got eclipse and have set up the emulator (using a mac btw)... now what do? I had a look around but couldn't find an existing guide. Please bear in mind I'm a total moron here - if there's a step-by-step guide somewhere then please do point me at it.

Apologies for being a total idiot, any help would be great - thanks!

Comment: do you have the android project imported in your eclipse project explorer?

Comment: Nope, that's what I'm trying to figure out how to do. The app is actually ready to go on the store, but I just want to run it in the emulator :/

Comment: well you need the project files. tell your friend to send you the project file, and then import it into eclipse

Comment: Yes I have those, but I don't know how to import them as a project...

Comment: in your eclipse, use `General > Existing Android-Project into Workspace`. But you will have to import the whole project manually if your friend created his project with AndroidStudio instead of Eclipse

Comment: @user3699020, Please upvote and accept as answer coz' it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial would help you http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-hello-world-example/

Btw, step by step is that,

1. You have already created your project.
2. Create a new **AVD** (*Android Virtual Device*) for the device setting you require. (http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)
3. In eclipse project explorer, as shown in the image http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/doc/images/intro/eclipse_run_as_android_application.png

   ```
   Right Click your project --> Run As --> Android Application
   ```

   Or

   ```
   Right Click your project --> Run As --> Run Configurations --> Select Device
   ```

With this you can view your app in the emulator.

Comment: Thanks very much - I've actually already got that far, so it might seem a bit confusing the way I'm wording it. Basically, I already have all the code, a folder with manifest.xml, assests, bin, gen, libs etc etc in it, and an .apk file, but I simply do not know how to open it in the emulator. It's basically store-ready, I just want to run it! I know that sounds daft sorry! Can you help?

Comment: Yes Sure! Happy to help! Have you configured the emulator? The emulator in this case is called the AVD.

Comment: yes, I have that all set up and ready to go - I'm guessing I just need to open something as a project, but have no idea how to..

Comment: Refer this image. It would help <http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/doc/images/intro/eclipse_run_as_android_application.png>

Comment: This entire link would also help you <http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/getting-started/running-an-application-in-emulator-and-on-device.html>

Comment: @user3699020, Please upvote and accept as answer coz' it helped you :)